# Change domain redirect all URLs exactly except one URL that must be redirect to a different URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Change domain from `example.net` to `example.com`.
I must to redirect all URLs exactly `except` one URL that must be redirected to different URL.

To redirect all URLs exactly (www and non-www) I use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (w*)example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Till here everything is perfect.

But I need one URL from old domain to be redirected to a different URL:

`example.net/en` to be redirected to `example.com/abc` instead of `example.com/en`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128426/redirect-all-urls-exactly-except-one-url-that-must-be-redirected-to-a-different/128427#128427

I do not understand why on #StackOverFlow I get negative vote for this question.

I hope to help other users this fix!